# Jquery dont working on localhost

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var len = $(':checkbox:checked').length;

    $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', len >= 2)
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="abc" style="width:10px">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="qwe" style="width:10px">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="xyz" style="width:10px">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="pqr" style="width:10px">
</body>
</html>
```

this is running in this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ESH54/ but i cant make it work in localhost. Any idea?

Comment: The javascript code runs before the rest of the HTML document is loaded.

Comment: I don't think so... I'm posting this and i'm trying to make it work

Comment: Okey, the problem it was that. I copy-pasted below and its work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try to access elements that doesn't exist at this time. You have to wait for the dom to be ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function(){
        var len = $(':checkbox:checked').length;

        $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', len >= 2)
    });
});
</script>
```

Also see: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Your jsfiddle works, because the script is wrapped inside the head in the window.onload handler (click at the icon next to "Javascript" to see the configuration / this detail)

Answer (score 0):

You try moving js code to the bottom of the page. It should be after the html is genarated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="abc" style="width:10px">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="qwe" style="width:10px">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="xyz" style="width:10px">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4[]" value="pqr" style="width:10px">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var len = $(':checkbox:checked').length;

    $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', len >= 2)
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what this code does